# Simple Insert works with phpmyadmin but not with php

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to insert this query with mysql_query

```
INSERT INTO um_group_rights (`um_group_id`,`cms_usecase_id`,`um_right_id`) VALUES (2,1,1) ; 
INSERT INTO um_group_rights (`um_group_id`,`cms_usecase_id`,`um_right_id`) VALUES (2,2,1) ; 
INSERT INTO um_group_rights (`um_group_id`,`cms_usecase_id`,`um_right_id`) VALUES (2,3,1) ; 
INSERT INTO um_group_rights (`um_group_id`,`cms_usecase_id`,`um_right_id`) VALUES (2,4,1) ;
```

and it returns:
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; INSERT INTO um_group_rights (`um_group_id`,`cms_usecase_id`,`um_right_id`) V' at line 1

it obviously has a problem with the semicolon but i dont understand why. it works without a problem in phpmyadmin.
php version is 5.2.6

Comment: Besides that code snippet, can you post the code that calls the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be sure : when you are trying to execute these 4 queries from PHP, you're calling `mysql_query` four times ?

For instance :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO um_group_rights (`um_group_id`,`cms_usecase_id`,`um_right_id`) VALUES (2,1,1)");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO um_group_rights (`um_group_id`,`cms_usecase_id`,`um_right_id`) VALUES (2,2,1)");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO um_group_rights (`um_group_id`,`cms_usecase_id`,`um_right_id`) VALUES (2,3,1)");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO um_group_rights (`um_group_id`,`cms_usecase_id`,`um_right_id`) VALUES (2,4,1)");
```

What I mean is : you cannot send several distinct queries at once, with only one call to [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) *(quoting, emphasis mine)* :

> `mysql_query()` sends a unique query
>   **(multiple queries are not supported)** to the currently active
>   database on the server that's
>   associated with the specified
>   `link_identifier` .

You have to "separate" your queries -- which is probably something phpMyAdmin does without telling you.

And, as [@Alexandre pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162407/alexandre-jasmin) in the comments :

> The query string should not end with a
>   semicolon.

If you are using the [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions (and not `mysql_*`) to access your database, you could try using [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Unfortunately, there is such function for `mysql_*`.

(BTW : the `mysql_*` API is the old one -- it would be better, especially for a new project, to use `mysqli_*`)

---

**Edit after the comment :**

If it's about performances, yes, doing a single call to the database, instead of four successive `PHP <-> MySQL` calls, could be better.

In this case, you could try using the insert syntax that allows to insert several lines at once ; see [12.2.5. INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) in MySQL's manual *(quoting)* :

> `INSERT` statements that use `VALUES`
>   syntax can insert multiple rows.
>   
> To do this, include multiple lists
>   of column values, each enclosed within
>   parentheses and separated by commas.
>   
> Example:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
> ```
>
> The values list for each row must be
>   enclosed within parentheses.

Comment: thanks, i didnt know that.... still pretty stupid imo.
i though i would have better preformance with more queries in one string, thats why i did that

Comment: Also quoting the mysql_query() documentation: `The query string should not end with a semicolon.`

Comment: @Alexandre : thanks for pointing that out : I had removed the semicolons without really knowing if it would change anything ;; I've editing my answer to insist on that too.

Comment: @xarfai : I've edited my answer to provide some additionnal information ;; especially about an INSERT syntax that allows one to insert several lines in only one query -- maybe that can help too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Unlike phpMyAdmin, [**mysql_query()**](http://de.php.net/mysql_query) can execute only one query at a time.

You would have to split the string, or switch over to [**mysqli**](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) and [**mysqli_multi_query()**](http://de.php.net/mysqli_multi_query).