# Nested/Subqueries cuasing syntax erros using mysqli extension; though syntactically correct

Tags: php, mysqli, subquery

I'm using the mysqli improved extension (procedural style) and have just ran into an anomaly when running sub-queries through the mysqli_query() function.

**Update: After much troubleshooting I've found the *cause* of the error is setting the '@rank' variable. I tried a query without setting such '@var's and works fine. But they are needed...  - Does PHP not pass 'SET @example = x' correctly to mysql, or need to be escaped somehow?**

The query is as follows:

```
SET @rank = -1; 
SELECT rank FROM (
SELECT @rank := @rank +1 AS rank, location, fileName 
FROM assets WHERE idUser = '32'
ORDER BY UploadTimestamp DESC) AS rank_number 
WHERE photoFileName = 'filename.ext'
```

The query executes correctly within Phpmyadmin and [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348925/simple-insert-works-with-phpmyadmin-but-not-with-php) posts direct towards the multi_query method however this doesn't seem to be a query that can be split into multiple queries? It bound to have a simpler solution (perhaps)

The php query is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $queryAsAbove);
```

The query *is* dynamic (it gets passed a filename) though this is escaped and not the cause.
Finally the query is within a mysqli_fetch_array loop though variables have been checked for same-name conflict.

The sql @rank variable is set to -1 in order for the fetched array to be indexed at 0. The query is simply uses to identify the row number from a SELECT query as described [here](http://www.fromdual.com/ranking-mysql-results).

Error is as follows:

```
"You have an error...the right syntax to use near 'SELECT rank FROM (SELECT @rank :=
@rank +1 AS rank, location, filename' at line 2"
```

(Only has error when ran using php, not if query copied into PMA)

Thank you for your time, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't you meant to use [multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) ?

Because mysqli_query can't run more than one query

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out- Yes, though I'm just referencing a suggestion I researched but is no longer valid (question now updated) thank you. It seems to be only when SET @var = x is used in the query

Comment: @user885983: Yes, that's exactly that problem. `SET @var = x` is first query, SELECT is second one.

Comment: I see, are you saying I should therefore split the query (using multi_query?) and store the SET `@var = x` as a stored query? And then reference that with the second half of the query..

Comment: `I should therefore split the query (using multi_query?)` this

Comment: I'm sorry I may be mistaken but I do not understand the need /how for using multi_query for example this (albeit unnecessary) query uses a nested query but executes Ok without multi_query:

`SELECT FileName FROM ( SELECT virtualFolderName, photoFileName FROM photos WHERE idUser = '67' ORDER BY UploadTimestamp DESC) AS mySubquery WHERE FileName = 'filename.txt'`